# vpn client can not connect to hosts over the vpn server

Tags: windows-10, vpn, routing, windows-firewall, connection-sharing

**The goal is to provide connection from external notebook to the local hosts** via Internet as they are in the same local network.

All machines's OS = Windows 10

Hosts (static IP 192.168.137.X) are few machines connected to the hub via cables.

X: 1 - 9

Gate: 192.168.137.1

Mask: 255.255.255.0

Among these machines there is one with 2 network cards (ethernet). The built-in card is connected to the hub (static IP 192.168.137.1). The additional card (connected to the Internet provider) has static public IP (v4), and this connection is shared in its settings. Let us denote public IP as A.B.C.D and this special machine as SERVER.

VPN server is running by SERVER. It is configured in this way: Control Panel --> Network and Sharing Center --> Change adapter settings --> New Incoming Connection. Windows firewall allows "Routing and remote access". Needed A.B.C.D ports (UDP 500, 4500, 1701) are allowed by Internet provider (checked).

Notebook has wi-fi connection to the home router (router's WAN port has public IP = E.F.G.H, and LAN is 10.0.0.1/255.255.255.0). VPN client (notebook) configured in the same manner as the VPN server: Control Panel --> VPN --> Add --> A.B.C.D., user/password, Automatic protocol. Connection is established. To save access to the Internet I unchecked "Use default gateway on remote network".

**PROBLEM. The goal is not reached. I can not use services running by the hosts. Actually I  can not ping them.**

Comments:

- According to the manuals I tried to add some routes to notebook's table and SERVER's table
- I tried to play with IPs for VPN network (range, static/DHCP)

Unfortunately, it doesn't help, but I'm not sure I do it right.

Please, say what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use only one cable on ethernet to test. Normally, the VPN service provider(VPN server) require "authentic method" and "dial" when you connect to the VPN service(VPN server).

What are the both meaning? The dial meaning you need a remote address such as IP or "domain name"-"www.example.com".

The authentic method is a mechanism the service provider providing the service to client with an authenticating behavior. So, the both side, the VPN server and VPN client are able to translate information between each other.

The real instance you are able to use a open vpn service such as this, http://www.vpngate.net/en/

You need to download the client software on windows. Then, you see there are many vpn server(service provider). You can know what I said in this real example.

So, back to your case, is there a router in front of your VPN server machine such as router? The router provide the firewall feature or NAT feature to make the machines have no way to provide the VPN service.

In the other side, what is about your network environment on client side? If there are router in front of your client machine, the router has the same ability such as firewall and NAT feature.

Comment: VPN server machine is connected to the Internet directly by network card. It has public IP denoted as A.B.C.D  in the text above.

Comment: On client side I have the router in front of my notebook.

Comment: Dial is OK. Connection is established. I have remote address (mentioned public IP). By the way, I have domain name too.

Comment: I know there are a way to build connections by PPPOE directly via your VPN server. In the other way, there is a router in front of your server. The router make the PPPOE dial to the internet. The router has NAT and DHCP to make the machines behind itself connect to the internet. You directly use the server to connect the internet on a required situation for those A B C D machines. But, I don’t know the IP is static or floating. You can use “curl -s http://ipv4.icanhazip.com” this command to check your server IP. If the IP rotate so frequently, this is a potential matter to have unstable scene.

Comment: "static public IP". I'm absolutely sure.

Comment: Sorry. I don’t know why. There are many vpn type, PPTP L2TP SSLVPN OpenVPN. You can try among them. Alternatively, there are some methods such as reverse ssh,   reverse proxy and nat reflections. But, they are not vpn this method. The feature is different.